# how to upload a pdf file to ftp server using file upload controller?

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I want to upload a pdf file to ftp server. I have done it this way but it shows an error:

> System.Net.WebException: The requested URI is invalid for this FTP
>   command.

```
  protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Net.FtpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://www.xxxx.co/yyyy/");
    rq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "*****");
    rq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    System.IO.Stream fs = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();
    System.IO.Stream ftpstream = rq.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
```

please help. how can I upload a pdf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxxx.co/yyyy/");
```

Your command creates a directory instead, you need to add the file name

```
System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxxx.co/yyyy/file.pdf");
```